# Domain name pointing to an A record with valid certificate prompts an err_cert_common_name_invalid

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

So we wanted to have one of our domains in godaddy to point on another hosted service on another godaddy account. The site already has SSL in it and the other domain didn't we installed the certificate through autossl. But it prompted an error **err_cert_common_name_invalid** they said we should not use auto SSL if we are not in the same IP. so my question is what is the best way to handle this kind of issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a certificate valid for both names.

TLS certificates handle this using the Subject Alternate Name field.

Comment: So there should only be 1 certificate for both domains right? And I should upload it on the original hosting provider?

Comment: This is the easiest solution, yes. And you should *not* upload it; you should *automate* it.

Comment: Thanks man! Our provider made a mistake and was fixed now by adding our domain to their ssl.